# Is it bad practice to call a method inside an if/else condition?

Tags: java, if-statement, coding-style, conditional-statements

Is it considered bad practice to do this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scan.nextInt() == 5) {                //testing if input is equal to 5
    System.out.println("input equals 5");
}
```

What about:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
if(scan.nextInt() == scan.nextInt()) {    //testing if two inputted ints are equal to each other
    System.out.println("input1 equals input 2");
}
```

I read somewhere that this can cause "unexpected results" but I don't know what was meant by that. I have tested this quite a bit and haven't run into anything unexpected.

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: No it isn't. Perhaps you have misunderstood what you've read.

Comment: @Keppil I don't remember exactly, but it was somewhere on the internet, so its reliability is questionable.

Comment: This _can_ cause unexpected results if the methods aren't "pure". For example, if you decided to add another test to check whether `scanner.nextInt() == 7`, the test would read _another_ value from the `Scanner`. This is a very common bug in the usage of `Iterator` for example. So it's fine if you know want you're doing, but if you forget then...

Comment: @Alboz Thanks, now that I think about it, I read this on a random website, and its reliability is probably not so great.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see, thanks for explaining what could go wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't bad practice to call a method inside an if/else. Its fine especially when it returns a value you only need that once.

Answer (score 6):

The problem here is not that you call a method inside the condition of the `if` block. The problem is that your function is not **pure**, i.e., it has a side effect. If you have a look at @Krayo's example, you'll see how two seemingly equivalent pieces of code can have different behavior: `&&` does only execute the second expression, if the first expression evaluates to `true`. Analogous, `||` only executes the second expression, if the first is `false`.

Have a look at the [Command and Query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) principle. It states that your methods should either compute and return a value, or they should change the state of an object, but not both.

**Edit:** Also, have a look at the [Uniform Access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle) principle. The semantics of your program should not depend on whether you obtain a value through storage or through computation. If your program behaves differently when accessing a field than when executing a method that computes the same value, then you should probably fix your method. **Note:** behavior and performance are two pairs of shoes: Accessing a field will be faster than calculating a value.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an unexpected result:

```
public static int count;

public static void run1() {
    count = 0;
    long r1 = getNum1();
    long r2 = getNum2(); // it is called in any case, so count = 1
    if (r1 == 1L && r2 == 0L) { /* if r1 = 1 and r2 = 0 then print "blah"
                                   if r1 = 0 then r2 is not checked! (lazy evaluation) */
        System.out.println("blah");
    }
    System.out.println(count); // always print 1 (count = 1)
}

public static void run2() {
    count = 0;
    if (getNum1() == 1L && getNum2() == 0L) { /* if getNum1() = 1 and getNum2() = 0 then print "blah"
                                                 if getNum1() = 0 then getNum2() is not checked, so count = 0! */
        System.out.println("blah");
    }
    System.out.println(count); // depends on the getNum1() result
}

// return 0 or 1 depending on milliseconds of the current time is even or odd
public static long getNum1() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2L;
}

// same as getNum1() and addition set count to 1
public static long getNum2() {
    count = 1;
    return System.currentTimeMillis() % 2L;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't completely understand what is going on in this code (I am a beginner in Java). Could you explain what the code does and how it would cause an unexpected result?

Comment: I expanded it with some comments.

Comment: Oh, I see the potential problem, thank you very much!